# Bootstrap 3 modal opening with a restricted height despite not height being set?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have a "Check Availability" button which opens a Bootstrap 3 modal on this page:
http://www.cairnsmorecottages.co.uk/tackroom-cottage-newton-stewart.php

This opens correctly.

I have EXACTLY the same button on the following page, the only difference is that it is titled "Tackroom Cottage", but this time it opens with a restricted height.  What gives?
http://www.cairnsmorecottages.co.uk/contact.php

The only difference is that I have two modals on the contact page but why would that restrict the height of the second referenced one?

Is it not possible to have two Bootstrap 3 modals on one page perhaps?
Thank you.
NJ

Comment: You can have more than 1 modals in a single page...

Comment: I think its because of opacity in .modalDialog css make it value as initial

Comment: The links do not come up for me.  Can you put the code into JSFiddle when you get a second?  Thanks!

Comment: Here is a Bootply, but it's not doing what my page is doing at all, in fact it's displaying the modal without having clicked either of the two available buttons... http://www.bootply.com/oMOWnstCem

Comment: Have amended the Bootply (above) - you'll see the problem.  This is exactly what's happening on my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the two frames containing the availability calendars have the same ID, so when the `resizeCrossDomainIframe` function fires it is grabbing the first iframe (which is closed), calculating it's height (which will be 0 or null, I didn't look at it closely enough to be honest) and then using that calculation to resize your iframe's height.

For absolute minimum code changes you can simply do the following.

Change the first iframe to this

```
<iframe width="100%" id="myFrame1" src="http://www.countrycottagesonline.com/project/site/calendar_new.php?cid=1123" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onload="resizeCrossDomainIframe('myFrame1','http://www.countrycottagesonline.com');"></iframe>
```

Take note that the id has changed to `myFrame1` (I would probably change this to something more meaningful like `stableCottageCalanderFrame`) and this has been reflected in the inline `onload` script `onload="resizeCrossDomainIframe('myFrame1','http://www.countrycottagesonline.com');"`

Then just do the same with the other one

```
<iframe width="100%" id="myFrame2" src="http://www.countrycottagesonline.com/project/site/calendar_new.php?cid=3329" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onload="resizeCrossDomainIframe('myFrame2','http://www.countrycottagesonline.com');"></iframe>
```

Again, maybe change that ID to something like `tackroomCalendarFrame`.

You should also be aware that you have two identical functions in your page. Your `resizeCrossDomainIframe` function appears twice in two separate script tags for no good reason (I'm guessing a bit of copy pasta was used here). Save future headaches and get rid of one of them. Whilst you're at it you could move it down to the bottom of your page (just before the closing `</head>` tag) in order to help page load speed and generally keep things more organised. It's best practice to put scripts at the bottom of the page where possible, although in this case it makes no difference.

Here's a fixed Bootply for you as well - http://www.bootply.com/xRbZP13GXD